# MacBook Pro early battery degradation

Tags: battery

My MacBook Pro (A2251) battery is 78% max capacity after only 785 charge cycles and 3976mAh. Is this okay?
I have plugged it in overnight in the first year or 2 of owning it but now I have AlDente installed.
I also couldn't. see the max capacity from System Settings or System Information so I calculated from the capacity when it was new (5086mAh). Also, I regularly play Roblox on it and it sometimes maxes out the fans and throttles.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show another poor battery and confirm @Ruskes answer, see my battery report:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Only 785 charge cycles".

Apple considers the battery "used" when it is beyond 1,000 cycles. 80% of design capacity is another measurement by which Apple considers the battery due for replacement; but the two are separate.

Yours is a 2020 MBP, and the last few Intel laptops ran 'quite hot', which is likely a significant factor -- more so than leaving it plugged in overnight. 3 years or so is at the low end of average life, but not totally unexpected.